# Cannot borrow data in dereference of `std::sync::RwLockReadGuard<'_, LruCache<i32, bytes::Bytes>>` as mutable

Tags: caching, rust, mutable

I am quite new to Rust. I'm trying to build a global cache using lru::LruCache and a RwLock for safety. It needs to be globally accessible based on my program's architecture.

```
//Size to take up 5MB
const CACHE_ENTRIES: usize = (GIBYTE as usize/ 200) / (BLOCK_SIZE);

pub type CacheEntry = LruCache<i32, Bytes>;
static mut CACHE : CacheEntry = LruCache::new(CACHE_ENTRIES);
lazy_static!{
    static ref BLOCKCACHE: RwLock<CacheEntry> = RwLock::new(CACHE);
}


//this gets called from another setup function
async fn download_block(&self,
        context: &BlockContext,
        buf: &mut [u8],
        count: u32, //bytes to read
        offset: u64,
        buf_index: u32
    ) -> Result<u32> {

    let block_index = context.block_index;

    let block_data : Bytes = match {BLOCKCACHE.read().unwrap().get(&block_index)} {
        Some(data) => data.to_owned(),
        None => download_block_from_remote(context).await.unwrap().to_owned(),
    };

//the rest of the function does stuff with the block_data
}

async fn download_block_from_remote(context: &BlockContext) -> Result<Bytes>{
    //code to download block data from remote into block_data

    {BLOCKCACHE.write().unwrap().put(block_index, block_data.clone())};
    Ok(block_data)
}
```

Right now I am getting an error on this line:

```
let block_data = match {BLOCKCACHE.read().unwrap().get(&block_index)} {
```

"cannot borrow as mutable" for the value inside the braces.

"help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `std::sync::RwLockReadGuard<'_, LruCache<i32, bytes::Bytes>>`"

I have gotten some other errors involving ownership and mutability, but I can't seem to get rid of this. Is anyone able to offer guidance on how to get this to work, or set me on the right path if it's just not possible/feasible?

Comment: You need to use `.write()` to get mutable access to the contents of a `RwLock`. `.read()` only gives immutable access.

Comment: @Locke that defeats the whole purpose of an `RwLock`, though. I think his question was not *how do I get writable access* but rather *why do I need writable access here*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that [`LruCache::get()`](https://docs.rs/lru/latest/lru/struct.LruCache.html#method.get) requires mutable access to the cache object. (Reason: it's a cache object, which has to change its internal state when querying things for the actual caching)

Therefore, if you use an `RwLock`, you need to use the `write()` method instead of the `read()` method.

That said, the fact that `get()` requires mutable access makes the entire `RwLock` pretty pointless, and I'd use a normal `Mutex` instead. There is very rarely the necessity to use an `RwLock` as it has more overhead compared to a simple `Mutex`.